# Zynga Scroller bounce issue

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am currently using [Zynga's scrolling library](https://github.com/zynga/scroller) to swipe/scroll through my page content one page at a time.

When I try setting the bouncing option to false, to prevent the next page from bouncing once it is in view, the scrolling does not stop at that page but continues scrolling through all the pages without stopping until the last page is reached.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: This issue has been resolved. It was an actual bug in the Zynga library which I fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. It was a bug in the Zynga library which I had to fix.

Comment: What did you do to fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/VaroonG/scroller/commit/cf2495b168c63c3842d0419ea53634e32b2ca162